# max-width and max-height on background image

Tags: html, css

I want to show an background-image while hovering over the normal image. They both should have the same height and width. I thought to make it work by giving the div with the background image `display: inline-block` so it takes the same size as the image, but that makes it so the `width: 100%` and `height: 100%` of the image stop working cause they try to take 100% of the width from the `inline-block` element.

How can I make the `background-image` the same size as the `image` while keeping the values of `height` and `width` as ..% of the `.box` div.

```css
.box{
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.around-image{
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/600x400) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
}

img{
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.helper{
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
}   

img:hover{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="around-image">
    <span class="helper"></span><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
  </div>  
</div>
```

---

**Edit**
Thanks to the answer from @dbigpot I probably got a better solution which is changing the `background-image` on hover. Only problem is that I can't use the `max-height` and `max-width` on the image and I need that part of the code so my images always look good inside of the div.

Is there anyway to set `max-height` or `max-width` on a `background-image`?

```css
.box{
  margin: 30px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/300x200) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.box:hover{
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/200x300) no-repeat center;
}

.height p{
  position: absolute;
  left: -60px;
  top: 45%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.width p{
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: -40px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="height">
    <p>height: 200px</p>
  </span>
  <div class="width">
    <p>width: 400px</p>
  </span>
</div>
```

As you see, the 300x200 image is stretched over an area of 400x200. I don't want the image to stretch.

Comment: Any reason you’re not applying `background-image` _to_ the actual image then?

Comment: @CBroe when I hover over the image the image gets `opacity: 0;` so the `background-image` will not be visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent stretching of the *image* just change the *value* of the `background-size` *property* to `contain`:

```
.box {
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```css
.box {
  margin: 30px;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/300x200) no-repeat center;
  background-size: contain;
  position: relative;
}

.box:hover {
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/200x300) no-repeat center;
}

.height p {
  position: absolute;
  left: -60px;
  top: 45%;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.width p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 40%;
  top: -40px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="height">
    <p>height: 200px</p>
  </div>
  <div class="width">
    <p>width: 400px</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try using `background-size:cover`

```css
.box{
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.around-image{
  background: url(http://via.placeholder.com/300x200/ff0000) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: inline-block;
}

img{
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.helper{
 display: inline-block;
 height: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
}   

img:hover{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="around-image">
    <span class="helper"></span><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300x200">
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried `background-size: cover` but I don't see a difference.

Comment: Sorry I also realised that late when I posted.
I removed the black border as that was affecting the image size. I have edited the snippet.

Comment: Oh I see, but that was actually not the thing I was looking for. The image has to be `max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; width: 100%; height: 100%;` of the `.box` element, but because of the `.around-image{ display: inline-block;} ` the image doesn't take the good width and heights.

Comment: So you are trying to stretch the image to the size if its parent contianer?

Comment: I have edited my question and I hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this -

```css
#target {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRN_bhuF3l7rhMNNBk4lgEoOp2qnB2TAJd5h_rVGtsWzZ0K0uzs');
}

#target:hover {
  background: url('http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-KdSQjJhV4jI/TpMRe96ndUI/AAAAAAAACfQ/BC6ZMvbp_DA/s1600/gerbera-elegant-flowers-9.jpg');
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
```

Adjust the background css properties to suit your need.

Comment: Oh, changing the `background-image` on hover and make both the images as `background-image`. Yeah that's probably the solution, the only problem is that I can't set `max-width` and `max-height` of the `background-image`

Comment: You can adjust that with
    `background-size: 400px 300px;`
    `background-position: 120px 100px;`